# Excluding lines where column value exists in another file

Tags: awk, grep

I've got 2 `.csv` files listing IPs and names.

My goal is to create an output file that lists all lines from `file_a.csv`, excluding the ones were the `ip` already exists in `file_b.csv`, no matter what the value the column `name` has there.

file_a.csv:

```
ip,name,kind
10.0.0.1,AA,ID
10.0.0.2,AA,ID
10.0.0.3,BB,ID
10.0.0.4,BB,ID
10.0.0.5,CC,ID
10.0.0.6,CC,ID
```

And file_b.csv:

```
ip,name,kind
10.0.0.1,AA,ID
10.0.0.3,XX,ID
10.0.0.5,YY,ID
10.0.0.7,ZZ,ID
10.0.0.9,ZZ,ID
```

Output file for this sample would be:

```
ip,name,kind
10.0.0.2,AA,ID
10.0.0.4,BB,ID
10.0.0.6,CC,ID
```

Until now, I'm guessing a loop with awk might work, but I'm not sure how to perform the comparison:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next}; <comparison missing>' file_a.csv file_b.csv > new_file.csv
```

Any other commands that achieve the target are welcome.

Comment: Aside from accept an answer, you can also upvote it to show your gratitude. And when there're other good answers, you can choose the best one, not necessarily the first one. Also you could / should show your gratitude to other good answers by upvote them, since they spent their time to help you and gave you good solutions.  --  Seeing that you are a 5 year old member of SO but aren't doing these already, so maybe it's worth mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){delete a[$1]} END{for(i in a){if(a[i]){print a[i]}}}' file_a.csv  file_b.csv
```

In order to take care of headers in files try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
FNR==1 && ++count==1{
  print
  next
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$0
  next
}
($1 in a){
  delete a[$1]
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(a[i]){
      print a[i]
    }
  }
}' Input_file_a.csv   Input_file_b.csv
```

Output will be as follows.

```
ip,name,kind
10.0.0.2,AA,ID
10.0.0.4,BB,ID
10.0.0.6,CC,ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward way:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0;next}!($1 in a)||FNR==1' b a
ip,name,kind
10.0.0.2,AA,ID
10.0.0.4,BB,ID
10.0.0.6,CC,ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
$ awk -F"," ' { if(NR==1) print; a[$1]=ARGIND; b[$1]=$0} END { for( i in a) { if(a[i]==1) print b[i] } } ' filea.csv fileb.csv
ip,name,kind
10.0.0.2,AA,ID
10.0.0.4,BB,ID
10.0.0.6,CC,ID
$
```

Comment: @ZeldaElf, please try this solution as well.